# Merge multiple columns into one with index column in PySpark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I am trying to merge/concatenate 4 columns with an additional index column.
But I am facing difficulty when I am trying to choose only one value.

example:

| Index | Column_1 | Column_2 | Column_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Null | Null |
| 2 | B | B | Null |
| 3 | Null | C | Null |
| 4 | Null | Null | D |

This should be the output:

| Index | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | D |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`coalesce`** function to create value column.

**`Example:`**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,'A',None,None),(2,'B','B',None),(3,None,'C',None),(4,None,None,'D')],['index','column_1','column_2','column_3'])
df.withColumn("value",coalesce(col("column_1"),col("column_2"),col("column_3"))).select("index","value").show(10,False)

#+-----+-----+
#|index|value|
#+-----+-----+
#|1    |A    |
#|2    |B    |
#|3    |C    |
#|4    |D    |
#+-----+-----+
```